# Import WSDL SOAP 1.1 file in Dotnet 6 workerservice

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl, visual-studio-2022

This "older" WSDL File of a SOAP 1.1 Interface in rpc style:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:intf="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns1="http://automationtool.webservice.server.ras.example.com" xmlns:tns2="http://automationtool.server.ras.example.com" xmlns:impl="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" targetNamespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice">
            <xs:import namespace="http://automationtool.webservice.server.ras.example.com" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://automationtool.server.ras.example.com" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOf_xs_string">
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <xs:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xs:string[]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOf_xs_long">
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <xs:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xs:long[]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOf_tns1_ServiceRASUser">
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <xs:attribute wsdl:arrayType="tns1:ServiceRASUser[]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://automationtool.webservice.server.ras.example.com">
            <xs:import namespace="http://automationtool.server.ras.example.com" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <xs:complexType name="ServiceRASUser">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="activationDate" type="xs:long" />
                    <xs:element name="alias" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="allowableCallingNumbers" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ciscoCommands" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xs_string" />
                    <xs:element name="comment" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="contractID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ddis" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xs_long" />
                    <xs:element name="dialInIpAddress" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="disabled" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="domain" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="group" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="internetAddress" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="mask" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="password" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="radiusCommands" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xs_string" />
                    <xs:element name="route" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="type" type="xs:int" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://automationtool.server.ras.example.com">
            <xs:import namespace="http://automationtool.webservice.server.ras.example.com" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" />
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <xs:complexType name="RasAutomationException">
                <xs:sequence />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="RasAutomationException">
        <wsdl:part name="fault" type="tns2:RasAutomationException" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getUserResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="getUserReturn" type="tns1:ServiceRASUser" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getUserRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="domain" type="xs:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="userName" type="xs:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateUserRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="user" type="tns1:ServiceRASUser" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateUserResponse" />
    <wsdl:portType name="AutomationToolWebService">
        <wsdl:operation name="updateUser" parameterOrder="user">
            <wsdl:input name="updateUserRequest" message="impl:updateUserRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="updateUserResponse" message="impl:updateUserResponse" />
            <wsdl:fault name="RasAutomationException" message="impl:RasAutomationException" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getUser" parameterOrder="domain userName">
            <wsdl:input name="getUserRequest" message="impl:getUserRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="getUserResponse" message="impl:getUserResponse" />
            <wsdl:fault name="RasAutomationException" message="impl:RasAutomationException" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:AutomationToolWebService">
        <wsdlsoap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
        <wsdl:operation name="updateUser">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input name="updateUserRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="updateUserResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="RasAutomationException">
                <wsdlsoap:fault use="encoded" name="RasAutomationException" namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getUser">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input name="getUserRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getUserResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="RasAutomationException">
                <wsdlsoap:fault use="encoded" name="RasAutomationException" namespace="http://example.com/ras/server/webservice" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="AutomationToolWebServiceService">
        <wsdl:port name="AutomationToolWebService" binding="impl:AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://127.0.0.1:15005/axis/services/AutomationToolWebService" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Generates `Warning: One or more errors occurred` if it is imported in Visual Studio 2022 via the included Service References tool.

Error Details:

```
The optional WSDL extension element 'fault' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/ras/server/webservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='getUser']/wsdl:fault[@name='RasAutomationException']
The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/ras/server/webservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='getUser']/wsdl:output[@name='getUserResponse']
The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/ras/server/webservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='getUser']/wsdl:input[@name='getUserRequest']
The optional WSDL extension element 'fault' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/ras/server/webservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='updateUser']/wsdl:fault[@name='RasAutomationException']
The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/ras/server/webservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='updateUser']/wsdl:output[@name='updateUserResponse']
The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://example.com/ras/server/webservice']/wsdl:binding[@name='AutomationToolWebServiceSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='updateUser']/wsdl:input[@name='updateUserRequest']
Fault named RasAutomationException in operation updateUser cannot be imported. Unsupported WSDL, the fault message part must reference an element. This fault message does not reference an element. If you have edit access to the WSDL document, you can fix the problem by referencing a schema element using the 'element' attribute.
```

Later on at the generated code some important parts are missing. So I was wondering if anyone else had issues with older WSDLs and dotnet 6 in VS 2022.

Comment: I had, I regenerated the contract and then I manually modified it.

Comment: Check namespaces (and version).  The schema may have changed

Comment: Thanks guys, I have tried to repair the WSDL File but in the end I did not manage to get it work. I am really not into dealing with SOAP and I am also very uset to Json and have little to no expiriance in XML stuff. Since I only have two calls: `getUser` and `updateUser`. I ended up to wirte those requests with a normal HttpClient and then deal with th xml's as `strings`.